# UBIFS: Unexpected behavior (wear leveling)

Tags: filesystems, embedded, embedded-linux

I have been playing around with [UBIFS](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html) some. One test I wrote was a stress test to see if the wear-leveling in the system works as expected. In a nutshell the test

- Writes a file with random data to the file system located on the ubi volume
- Verifies the file contents
- Deletes the file

This is test is done a certain number of times (around 200,000). The "stressed" UBI volume was mounted on another UBI volume. As expected, the maximum erase count for the "stressed" ubi volume went up. What I also noticed is that the maximum erase count for UBI volume of the mount location also went up. I would not have expected this.

1. Anyone know what might cause this? Something in UBI? Or some mechanism in the Linux kernel (like logging)?
2. Has anyone seen this type of behavior with other files systems that implement wear-leveling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two processes in the system communicate via a [Unix Domain Socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). This socket is created in the "mount" UBI volume (I know not a good location). When I moved this file to a RAM-based location (i.e. /tmp), the writes to the mount UBI volume stopped. During the stress test the socket existed, but was not being used. It would be good to know why the file system thinks it needs to write the file after every sync.

Answer (score 1):

First guess would be that access-time logging is turned on, or *maybe* modification-time if the tests are being done in the root of the "stressed" volume.  Most likely access-time - mount the outer filesystem (actually probably both) with -noatime.

Comment: Good idea, but I found this in the man page for mount: Mount options for ubifs:
"UBIFS is a flash file system which works on top of UBI volumes.     Note that atime is not supported and is always turned off."

Comment: Then I would assume it's some other data writes - it's a running linux system; various things write to disk (especially but not limited to /var).  You could mount a tmpfs/ramdisk on top of the ubifs using unionfs or another overlay filesystem to absorb the writes, and also let you then look at what's getting written and by whom